# Proving for sequences that "$K$th difference is constant" implies "$K$th degree polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Here's something that strikes me as clear but I couldn't prove it (I must be missing something simple):

Take a sequence $\{ a_n \}$. The first differences are the sequence $\{a^{(1)}_n\}$ where $a^{(1)}_n = a_n - a_{n-1} = a^{(0)}_n - a^{(0)}_{n-1}$, and so on, with

$$a^{(k)}_n = a^{(k-1)}_n - a^{(k-1)}_{n-1}$$

It makes sense to me that if $a^{(K)}_n$ is constant (and $a^{(k)}_n$ is nonconstant $\forall k < K$), then $a_n$ is an $K$th degree polynomial, first and foremost because of the corresponding relationship with derivatives.

But I couldn't manage to prove this (don't know where to start, really). Any hints for how to proceed (a full solution is also fine)

Comment: What is $a_n$ a number or a function?

Comment: number, let's say reals.

Comment: Then, what do you mean by $a_n$ is an $K$th degree polynomial?

Comment: it's a real-valued sequence, the closed form formula for which is a polynomial

Comment: You should image it like the mean value theorem. Just because that the derivative is **somewhere** zero, it needs not vanish everywhere.

Comment: so you have a counterexample

Comment: $f(x) = x^2, a_1 = f(-1), a_2 = f(1)$.

Comment: If you don't like that $a_n$ is constant, make an example with a cubic polynomial...

Comment: @user251257 are you trolling me? I get the feeling you're trolling me.

Comment: probably I just misunderstood your question. Could you be more specific what the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The formulation of your question is not sound.

> When considering a (let's say real-valued) sequence
>   \begin{align*}
>   (a_n)_{n\geq 0}
>   \end{align*}
>   we should keep in mind that this is a function which maps the *natural numbers* (i.e. the indices) to real numbers.
>
> \begin{align*}
>   a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
>   a(n)=a_n
>   \end{align*}
>
> On the other hand a real-valued polynomial $p(x)$ is (usually) defined from the real numbers to the real numbers.
>   \begin{align*}
>   p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
>   p(x)=\ldots
>   \end{align*}

The statement **$a_n$ is a $K$-th degree polynomial** is not correct. Try to reformulate the problem and maybe this will also help to solve it.